# No qualifying bean of type found for dependency:

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I get this error when I try to `Autowire` a class found in a dependent `jar` in my `spring-mvc` web app.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:         No qualifying bean of type [com.nyl.cs.lic.ws.LicenseCheckWS] found for   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:    {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I believe this entry in the application context file should allow the class to be discovered (and the fact it is in a jar file shouldn't matter). autodiscovery for other classes defined in packages within my webapp work.

webapp application context auto discovery.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.nyl.cs.lic.ws"/>
```

problem class, in jar file, this jar is referenced in webapp pom file.

```
@Service
package com.nyl.cs.lic.ws;
public class LicenseCheckWSClientImpl implements LicenseCheckWS
```

usage where I get the problem in my webapp

```
@Service
public class ManagementServiceImpl implements ManagementService
    @Autowired
    private LicenseCheckWS licenseToSellWebService;
```

However with a junit in my webapp I don't have a problem when I Autowire this same class.

```
@Autowired
ManagementService managementService;
```

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Please format it correctly. Put the code parts in code blocks.

Comment: Share your configuration. Usually that problem occurs when ComponentScan is not configured properly

Comment: What do you need to see besides what I posted?                       <context:component-scan base-package="com.nyl.cs.lic.ws"/>

Comment: I reviewed my configuration and found that I had added the  <context:component-scan base-package= entry to the wrong application context file. My application splits the application context configuration between a few files. It needed to be in the one specific for web servcie configuration.